# How do I bind the value of a text input to the added item from an each block in Svelte?

Tags: arrays, svelte, reactive, svelte-3

I have an array of objects:

```
 $: proponentInfo = [
    {
      id: 0,
      "First Name": "",
      "Last Name": "",
      "M.I.": "",
      Prefix: "",
      Suffix: "",
      Rank: "",
      School: "",
      Department: "",
    },
];
```

which takes values from the rendered dom:

```
{#each proponentInfo as proponent, i}
 <div>
   {#each Object.keys(proponent) as field}
       <label>
         {field}
           <input
             type="text"
             bind:value={proponentInfo[i][field]}
           />
```

and this is the button that adds a new entry into the array:

```
 <div
   on:click={() => {
     proponentInfo = [
       ...proponentInfo,
       proponentInfo[proponentInfo.length - 1],
     ];
   }}
 >
```

After adding a new item to the array, when I input something on the first item, it also appears on the second item. This is confusing because when I try to log the index of the item triggering the event, it correctly logs the index of that entry in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a reference to your already existing object to add a "new" one, so all changes will be reflected in both (since there's actually only one object). You need to actually copy it.

If your structure is flat (no nested objects) you can do `array = [...array, {...array[array.length - 1]}]` or `array.push(Object.assign({}, array[array.length - 1]))` or something similar.

If there is a possibility of nested object, shallow copies won't work, because you'll have the same problem of referencing the same sub-object instead of copying.
In that case, you should use a deep copy lib like lodash or rfdc.

If I were you, I would also define a const as a model of my object instead of referencing the last existing array member, so that you don't transfer existing values to the new object.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using Object.create(model) to add to the new array. It now works perfectly.

Comment: nice, I didn't know about Object.create()